# Javascript async/await error handling: match throwing function in catch block

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await

I have found several approaches to a clean error handling with async/await.

Some propose:

1. handling error immediately on promise with `.catch()` (but it mixes up Promise and await syntaxes)
2. having promises return `[data, err]` instead of throwing (but it uglifies code with error checks)
3. creating errors that inherit Error object and match on `instanceof` in the `catch` block (this one is nice and fine, but requires to define as many classes).

Before I implement option 3 in all my code, I am wondering why I can't find the following anywhere. If my AsyncFunction is not about to throw different errors, why not just match the function directly?

```js
async function a() {}
async function b() {
  throw b;
}
(async () => {
  try {
    await a();
    await b();
  }
  catch (err) {
    switch (err) {
    case a: console.log('a threw'); break;
    case b: console.log('b threw'); break; // this one is executed
    }
  }
}) ()
```

There may be obvious reasons why we should never do that, but I'm stuck there.

Comment: Or do it farther up the chain: `a().catch(() => /* a threw */`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: Yes that's option 1. It's nice but I'd rather keep error handling in the `catch` block if possible